# Why doesn't Command+Tab restore minimized windows on Mac?

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts

Yes, I know, you have to roll your finger to the <kbd>Option</kbd> button before you release <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. But why? Any conceivable reason behind this oddity?

Comment: Maybe apple.stackexchange.com would be a better place for this question.